# How to remove a pattern of characters from an array of strings in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex, filter, substring

[Live code](https://repl.it/BNQb/2)

I have an array of strings.  Each string represents a path. I need to remove everything before the locale code in this path. **I would like this to return a new array of clean paths.**

**Question:**  How to write and use `arr.filter()` to `match()` then remove all locale's pattern from the original string.

Code:

```
var thingy = ['thing/all-br/home/gosh-1.png','thing/ar_all/about/100_gosh.png','thing/br-pt/anything/a_noway.jpg'];
var reggy = new RegExp('/[a-z]{2}-[a-z]{2}|[a-z]{2}_[a-z]{2}/g');


var newThing = thingy.filter(function(item){
       return result = item.match(reggy);
    });
```

In the end, I would like to filter that original array `thingy` to `newThing` which the output should looks like:

```
console.log(newThing);
// ['home/gosh1.png','about/gosh.png','place/1noway.jpg']
```

Comment: just change `return result = item.match(reggy);` to `return item.match(reggy);`

Comment: still not working :(

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/tgL8seyk/1/ ? - if the regex is proper... haven't validated that part

Comment: @T.J.Crowder that was a mistake.. I'm sorry.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to transform the items in the array, `filter` isn't the right tool; `map` is the tool you use.

It *looks* like you just want to drop the middle part of the path:

```js
var thingy = ['home/all-br/gosh1.png', 'about/ar_all/gosh.png', 'place/br-pt/noway.jpg'];
var newThing = thingy.map(function(entry) {
  return entry.replace(/\/[^\/]+/, '');
});
snippet.log(JSON.stringify(newThing));
```

```html
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="//tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

That uses `/\/[^\/]+/`, which matches a slash followed by any sequence of non-slashes, and then usese `String#replace` to replace that with a blank string.

If you wanted to use capture groups instead to capture the segments you wanted, you'd do much the same thing, just change what you do in the `map` callback, and have it return the string you want for that entry.

Just as an example of changing things slightly, here's a similar thing that captures the first and last segments and reassembles them without the part of the middle:

```js
var thingy = ['home/all-br/gosh1.png', 'about/ar_all/gosh.png', 'place/br-pt/noway.jpg'];
var newThing = thingy.map(function(entry) {
  var match = entry.match(/^([^\/]+)\/.*\/([^\/]+)$/);
  return match ? match[1] + "/" + match[2] : entry;
});
snippet.log(JSON.stringify(newThing));
```

```html
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="//tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

Tweak as necessary.

Comment: `map` is really the right/best way to go, for this case.

Comment: @T.J. could you try with var thingy = ['thing/all-br/home/gosh-1.png','thing/ar_all/about/100_gosh.png','thing/br-pt/anything/a_noway.jpg']; as your staring array.

Comment: thus removing thing/<locale>/

Comment: @MatthewHarwood: Just tweak as required. This is the fundamental way you do it (well, this or use `match` and reassemble the string you want from capture groups and return that from the `map` callback).